# discord py - save a user posted image and delete the old one

Tags: discord.py

my bot should make embeds from all messages in a specific channel. He deletes every message, that's not in an embed and puts them automatically in an embed. Now, that's working, but I have problems with the pictures that my users upload.

**My question:** How can I save the picture that uploaded a user in a "log-channel" and get the new discord image link from that picture?

I need the "new discord image link" to put it in the embed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried "pic.save(pic.url)", but the bot says No such file or directory: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/792561722090848266/795048642892791878/2021-01-01_17_00_12-Window.png'

But like you can see, the file exists.

Comment: Hi. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] if you haven't already. Share your code, including what solutions you have tried so far, so that others can help you better

Answer (score 1):

a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/search.html?q=discord.Message) instance holds the `attachments` attribute, which will get you a list of the attachments to a message. You can then use [`discord.Attachment.to_file()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html?highlight=message%20attachments#discord.Attachment.to_file) to get a [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html?highlight=message%20attachments#discord.File) instance, which you can use in an embed.

Example:

```py
message = SomeMessageInstance
# realistically you should be looping over the attachments, and sending an embed for each
file = await message.attachments[0].to_file()
file.filename = 'image.png'
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url='attachment://image.png')

await Channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

Comment: But I need the image only temporarily for a few days. Not forever.

Comment: Converting it to a discord.File instance does not save the image.